# Proving $\mathrm{R}_{n}\mathrm{R}_{m} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{lcm(m,n)}$

Tags: group-theory

this exercise is for my group theory's lecture.

> Let $m,n>1$. Prove there are $a,b\in{\mathbb{Z}}$ such that
>
> $$ \frac{a}{n}+\frac{b}{m}=\frac{1}{k} $$
>
> where $k=lcm(m,n)$. Conclude that $\mathrm{R}_{n}\mathrm{R}_{m} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{k}$.
> With $\mathrm{R}_{n}$ the set of the n-roots of the unity.

I've proved the first one using

$$
k = \frac{|nm|}{(n,m)}=\frac{nm}{(n,m)}
$$

and by Bézout's identity there are $a,b\in{\mathbb{Z}}$ such that $(n,m)=an+bm$, then

$$
k = \frac{nm}{an+bm} \implies \frac{a}{m}+\frac{b}{n}=\frac{an+bm}{nm}=\frac{1}{k}
$$

But I don't know how use this to prove $\mathrm{R}_{n}\mathrm{R}_{m} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{k}$. I know that a regular element of $\mathrm{R}_{n}\mathrm{R}_{m}$ looks like
$$
e^{i(\frac{2\pi k_{1}}{n}+\frac{2\pi k_{2}}{m})} 
$$
wtih $k_{1}\in{\{0,\dots,n-1\}}$ and $k_{2}\in{\{0,\dots,m-1\}}$.
Is not natural for me how to define such isomorphism. Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to prove that $\text{R}_n \text{R}_m \cong \Bbb{Z}_k$ is to use the fact that if a finite group $G$ has an element of order $|G|$, then $G$ is cyclic (hence $G \cong \Bbb{Z}_{|G|}$).

Thus, all that you need to do is to show that the set
\begin{align}
\text{R}_n \text{R}_m = \left\{ \exp \left( \dfrac{2l_1\pi i}n + \dfrac{2l_2\pi i}m \right) \right. :\; & l_1 \in \{0,1,\dots,n-1\}, \\[-3mm]
& l_2 \in \{0,1,\dots,m-1\} \Big\}
\end{align}

has $k$ elements, and find one with order $k$ (use the previous part of the problem for this).

Comment: Thank you so much:)

Comment: Just one question, necessarily $0\leq a<n $ and  $0\leq b<m$, right?

Comment: @AlexeyCortés No, and it doesn’t matter, since $\exp \left( \frac{2l\pi i}d \right) = \exp \left( \frac{2(l \textrm{ mod } d)\pi i}d \right)$ where “$l \textrm{ mod } d$” is congruent to $l$ modulo $d$, and $0 \leq (l \textrm{ mod } d) < d$.